# HTML form won't validate

Tags: html

I made an HTML form for a client programming project I am working on. The form is not supposed to be connected to a server for the project, but it needs to have validation. I have tried using "required" but it doesn't seem to work. Adding in "placeholder" works though. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
<div id='details' style="right:30px;">
    <form name="details" method="post" id='detailsForm' onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        First Name:<br> <input type="text" name="firstName" required><br><br>
        Email Address:<br> <input type="email" name="emailAddress" placeholder="Enter a valid email address" required><br><br>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="slideOff('details');"/>
        <p>Sign up for our daily newsletter all about Istanbul - the greatest city in the world!</p>
    </form>     
</div>
```

Comment: where does `onclick="slideOff('details');"` come from?

Comment: I have a javascript function called slideOff, which makes the form slide off the page when you click the submit button.

Comment: So you want it NOT to be slided off, when there is no input?

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 validation triggers when you submit the form.

You don't have a submit button (only a button button), so that never happens.

Comment: I had tried the javascript validation way too. But I'm just wondering why the HTML validation doesn't work.

Comment: What have submitting anything to do with validation and placeholders?

Comment: @system0verl0ad — It doesn't work because, as I said in this answer, you aren't submitting the form.

Comment: @davidkonrad — As I said in the answer, validation is triggered by form submission. It has nothing to do with placeholders, as the question says: placeholders work fine for the OP.